# Placing a button on Video tag

Tags: css, html, video, video-streaming, media-queries

The problem is when viewing in full screen mode, the buttons are no longer visible over video player. How to show button over video player in full screen/normal screen mode?

```js
$('#btnFullscreen').on('click', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("hwyVideo");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
});
```

```css
.videoContainer {
   position: relative;
}
.videoContainer > .btnCamera {
     background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconslandplayer/PNG/64x64/CircleBlue/Play1Pressed.png') center center no-repeat;
     height: 128px;
     left: 22%;
     margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 20%;
     width: 128px;
     z-index: 1;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoContainer">
  <video id="hwyVideo" controls="controls" style="width: 42%; height: auto">
    <source src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
      <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
  </video>
  <div id="btnCamera" class="btnCamera"></div>

</div>

<input type="submit" id="btnFullscreen" data-role="none" name="btnPopupAddneModelOP" data-icon="check" value="Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: Please do not use blockquote formatting unnecessarily to highlight your question. Technology (or library) names are not required in title because they are already part of tags. Finally, do you mean *full screen/normal screen mode* or *full screen and normal screen mode*?

Answer (score 0):

You should call requestFullscreen on the video container element, so for example you can change

```
var elem = document.getElementById("hwyVideo");
```

to

```
var elem = document.getElementById("hwyVideo").parentNode;
```